# C: swapping two pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, swap

I would like to swap the value of 2 integers using pointers.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *temp;
    temp = &a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp;
}
```

why this doesn't work ?

error given:

```
incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int **'
```

Comment: Your compiler probably already told you. If not, try enabling warning messages.

Comment: Yes but why I can't do
    temp = &a ?

Comment: cos they're different data types

Comment: That makes `temp` a pointer to a pointer, which makes no sense. Try `int temp=*a; *a=*b; *b=temp;`

Comment: ah, you say this because a is already a pointer ?

Answer (score 3):

`temp` is a pointer. What you want is an `int` to take the value of what `a` is pointing to. You need to change `temp` to an `int`.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp;
}
```

You may want to follow a few tutorials on C to understand how pointers work. It's a bit much to explain over a Stack Overflow answer with the multitude of resources available online and in books.

Comment: I see. So &a doesn't exist ? a is the adress so &a is what ?

Comment: The address of the pointer variable. It's called a double pointer (int**).

Comment: @cuckcuc `&a` does exist but it is not relevant to your problem. You want to change the value of the location `a` is pointing to